# A simple debug visualizer for delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-2010

I gather some experience with the trial version of delphi 2010. 
I am looking for a simple debug visualizer, because the sample 
debug visualizers are not part of the trail. I do a lot with the 
new rtti type TValue and TValue.ToString can't be call from the 
debugger (results in an exception), so my idea is to write a 
debug visualizer for it. The format shoul look like

```
(<data-type)<ToString-value>
```

examples

```
(integer)5
(string)'Hello World'
(Array<String>)['a', 'list', 'of', 'items']
```

With a simple demo for a debug-value-replacer (I think this was the name :-) ) I can start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed on Torry that [Mitov Software](http://www.mitov.com/html/free_downloads.html) has a (free) sample debug visualizer with source. It may help you even though it does not do exactly what you need. I have not downloaded it myself.

Comment: Thanks, its interesting and usefull but it is based on IOTADebuggerVisualizerExternalViewer and I need to implement an IOTADebuggerVisualizerValueReplacer interface.

Comment: Note, now you have to go to "download -> free downloads", last link.

Answer (score 3):

I found a usefull article explaining how Delphi debugger vizualizers at https://web.archive.org/web/20210417082409/http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40268

/Johan

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 2010 ships with an example of both types of visualizers, including source. The StdStringVisualizer is a Value Replacer type visualizers. It's source in a default installation of RAD Studio 2010 is in C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\source\Win32\Visualizers\StdStringVisualizer.pas

Unfortunately, since you're using the trial, you won't have this file, and the license prohibits anyone from providing it to you. I guess you'll have to wait to write your debugger visualizer until you actually buy a license. :-)

Comment: But the license do not prohibit to give an example other than these from Embarcadero. I use the trial to check what is possible. Unfortunately I can not use the trial to check how to work with debug-visualizer. :-(