# Debugging TValue containing a string

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm having trouble to inspect the string value of a TValue variable while debugging. The hover menu doesn't show the string value and even adding it to the watch list seems tricky.

Given a very basic sample console  application, like

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Rtti;

var
  Value: TValue;
begin
  Value := 'Hello';
  WriteLn(Value.AsType<string>);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Adding a breakpoint to the `WriteLn` line, I can hover over the `Value` variable and see the value type, but there isn't really any information on the string value, see

[image: Variable in Debugger]

Next thing I tried was adding it to the watch list, using `.AsType<string>` - however watchlist errors - Internal Error in the sample application, E2531 (method requires explicit type arguments) in my real application. It made no difference to check/uncheck the option to allow side effects and functions
.
[image: Watch list error]

What finally worked was creating a function for the conversion, e.g.

```
function ValueToString(const Value: TValue): string;
begin
  Result := Value.AsType<string>;
end;
```

and using this in the watchlist. I had to use this function in aplication code though (e.g. in the `WriteLn` call in the sample) to avoid it being removed by the linker. This also means that I'll have to add this funtion or a unit containing this function to every unit I want to debug.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Some hints here perhaps: [A simple debug visualizer for delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1425988/576719).

Comment: And link to [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Debugger_Visualizers)

Comment: @LURD so writing my own debug visualizer for `TValue`? I'll definitely keep that in mind, but I hope that it's only a last resort option :)

Comment: You could ask in g+ DelphiDevelopers forum for advice as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `TValue`'s built-in `Value.ToString` works in a watch. `Value.AsString` also evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Value.AsVariant`, as well.